# Unable to authorize at Azure mobile app services using MobileServiceClient

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I’ve been trying to implement Azure Active Directory authentication for my Web app at Mobile app.
Mobile app has been configured as described in this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/#advanced) (used Alternative method).

> My Azure Active Directory app settings:
>   SIGN-ON URL: https:// <mymobileappname>.azurewebsites.net/
>   App ID URI: https:// <mymobileappname>.azurewebsites.net/
>   Reply URL: https:// <mymobileappname>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Also I’ve passed ClientID(b6da4c72-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e20d561b7906) and entityID(https:// sts.windows.net/e052874c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-afd774687ee8/) to mobile app authentication settings in the Azure portal and switched it ON.

At my Web app I do folowing:

1. Take token from Azure Active Directory

```cs
    public string GetAADToken()
    {
       string clientID = "b6da4c72-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e20d561b7906";
       string authority = "https://login.windows.net/<mytenant>";
       string resourceURI = "https://<mymobileappname>.azurewebsites.net/";
       var appKey = <mysecretvalidkeytakenfromazureactivedirecoryapp>";

       var authenticationContext= new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority);
       var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientID, appKey);
       var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resourceURI, clientCredential);
       return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

2. Authenticate with AAD token at Mobile app using [MobileServiceClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/2.0.1)(v2.0.1)

```cs
      MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("https://<mymobileappname>.azurewebsites.net/");
      var token = new JObject();
      token["access_token"] = GetAADToken();
      var res = client.LoginAsync("aad", token).Result;
```

This code sends authentication request to my mobile app

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://<mymobileappname>/.auth/login/aad', Version: 1.1, Headers:
{
    X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: 904579fa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-02efc7ba2937
    Accept: application/json
    User-Agent: ZUMO/2.0
    User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=2.0.31217.0)
    X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/2.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=2.0.31217.0)
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 1129
}}
```

In the POST-body sends json with AAD token.

The same solution was used for azure mobile services and works fine, but for Mobile app service I always get: 401 'Unauthorized'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Three questions:  1) Do you get the 401 Unauthorized for future connections (after the LoginAsync) or for the LoginAsync() call?  2) If the former, what does the client.CurrentUser look like?  3) What does your POST body actually look like?

Comment: 1) For LoginAsync() call, the request description pasted below.
2) CurentUser is null.
3) It looks like:
{
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE...long long AAD token above one thousand characters"
}

Comment: Another final question.  If you go to https://yourmobileapp/.auth/login/aad in a browser, does the process complete successfully, and do you have a cookie that contains a ZUMO token?  I'm thinking the auth setup is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AdrianHall.

Yes, this URL redirect me to Azure login page, authentication completes successfully. After authentication i see page with note "You have successfully signed in" and I found token only in url: 
mymobileapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#token=%7B%22authenticationToken%22%3A%22<token>%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22userId%22%3A%22sid%3A71ffd0850783ccb784e7c5821a4d32f9%22%7D%7D

Comment: @S.Afon - did you get this to work from the client and not from the browser?